# Use of 'temp' in pseudocode

Tags: arrays, algorithm, pseudocode

I tried researching here, and on the internet in general, but since pseudocode writing is rather diverse and many use different signs for different things, I couldn't find anything that might fit my question.

Given the following: an array A (not necessarily already sorted) of the order n, and the indexes p,r so that 1<=p<=r<=n;

I am given the following recursive algorithm (in pseudocode), and I wonder what specific two lines (bolded) in it do/mean:

> MAXB(A,p,r)
>
> > if p=r
> >
> > > then return A[p]
> >
> > **else temp<-----MAXB(A,p,r-1)**
> >
> > > **if temp>=A[r]**
> > >
> > > then return temp
> > >
> > > else return A[r]

I do not exactly understand the process that is done with the 'temp'. If it changes `MAXB(A,p,r)` into `MAXB(A,p,r-1)` how can it be compared to the value of `A[r]` at all? I know the algorithm certainly doesn't do what it is supposed to do, according to the description: return the index of the item with the highest value, between `A[p]` and `A[r]` - certainly doesn't do that, yet I am not sure how can the temp even be compared to any value.

Comment: They mean the author is bad at thinking up good variable names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks to me like `temp` is a variable.

---

It's making a recursive call to your funciton: `MAXB` and storing the value from that call in a variable called `temp`.

It's then checking whether or not `temp` is greater than or equal to `A[r]`, and if it is, than it returns `temp`.  If it is less than `A[r]` it returns `A[r]`

### __*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_

Here's an explanation of the entire function:

```
if p=r
    then return A[p]
```

if `p` and `r` are equal, than there is only one value between `A[p]` and `A[r]`, and therefore, that one values is the greatest and you return that value.

```
else 
    temp<-----MAXB(A,p,r-1)
```

You use your own function, `MAXB` to get the greatest value between `A[p]` and `A[r-1]`, and you store that in `temp`

```
if temp>=A[r]
    then return temp
else 
    return A[r]
```

you compare to greatest value between `A[p]` and `A[r-1]` to `A[r]`.  Whichever one is greater, must be the greatest value between `A[p]` and `A[r]`, and is therefore the value that you want to return.